# Xcode Simulator can't find any of my npm modules

Tags: ios, xcode, react-native, expo

I am building a react native app using Expo, for some reason I keep running into errors related to not being able to resolve modules when trying to launch the mobile app on an IOS simulator from xcode. The error does not appear when running the metro bundler from the terminal.

The specific error is:

```
Unable to resolve module @react-navigation/native-stack from /Users/user/Downloads/project/App.js: @react-navigation/native-stack could not be found within the project or in these directories:
```

In the project directory, I can confirm that the module exists in the node_modules folder where it should be.

I am stumped and any solution would be appreciated. I have tried cleaning the build, deleting the derivedData as well as uninstalling and re-installing the node modules.